# redirect 301 not working properly in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

htaccess 301 redirect. I have this old site which is for example http://test.org/conference I want to redirect it to conference.test.org
What happened is the 301 redirect in my `.htaccess` file is quite buggy.

Here is my 301 redirect htaccess code below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/http://test.org/conference(/)?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://conference.test.org/? [R=301,L]
```

When I test this one it runs and redirects correctly. But when I test it over and over again. It seems not to redirect anymore.

Can someone help me have a htaccess 301 redirect code?

Any help is much appreciated.TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^conference/?$ http://conference.test.org/ [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Please note that `%{REQUEST_URI}` only contains the *path* of the URI, so not the protocol and the hostname. Reason is that the evaluation is performed *inside* a http host. This is explicitly pointed out in the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Depending on your http hosts setup you *might* also have to add a condition to prevent an endless redirection loop:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^conference\.test\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^conference/?$ http://conference.test.org/ [R=301,L,QSA]
```

But usually that is *not* required, since the rule should be defined inside the `test.org` http host...

Comment: your code seems to work.. but all the /conference link will be affected like for exampl 
http://test.org/conference/travel it will also redirect.. i want only the 
http://test.org/conference link will be redirected to conference.test.org

Comment: Sorry, that was not clear from your question. I modified the example according to that.